# Which Black Market decals come out of which crates?

Tags: rocket-league

There seems to be a lot of confusion around the rocket league community regarding which Black Market decals come out which crates. 
Crates 1, 2, 3, and 4.

These are the Universal Black Market decals thus far.

- Biomass
- Heatwave
- Hexed
- Labyrinth
- Parallax
- Slipstream
- Tora
- 20xx

As far as I know, Biomass and Hexed only come from Championship Crate 4. I've had people tell me they've gotten Heatwave from crate 4 as well. I think this question is also important in terms of people buying a specific crate thinking, the black market item they desire is in there.

Can anyone shed light on the topic? Thanks.

Comment: http://rocketleague.wikia.com/wiki/Crates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meilzus your answer is close, but actually wrong. I posted this question a long time ago, and since then i've watched many unboxings. Here is the breakdown.

**--- Black Market Items Released ---**

**Championship Crate 1:** Labyrinth, Slipstream

**Championship Crate 2:** Heatwave, Parallax

**Championship Crate 3:** No New Black Market Decals

**Championship Crate 4:** Biomass, Hexed

**Player's Choice Crate:** No New Black Market Decals

**Turbo Crate:** Tora, 20xx

**---  Current Possible Outcomes in Crates---**

**Championship Crate 1**: Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax

**Championship Crate 2**: Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax

**Championship Crate 3**: Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax

**Championship Crate 4**: Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax, Biomass, Hexed

**Player's Choice Crate:** Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax, Biomass, Hexed

**Turbo Crate:** Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax, Biomass, Hexed, Tora, 20xx

**Nitro Crate:** Labyrinth, Slipstream, Heatwave, Parallax, Biomass, Hexed, Tora, 20xx

As you can see, for every new crate to get released, it's still possible to get older mystery decals in those crates. But it's not possible to get New Mystery Decals in older crates. The only exception to this, for whatever reason, mystery decals released in crate 2 could also be found in crate 1. I think after crate 4's introduction, they changed the equation to fit the model I've pointed out.

Comment: bubbly is in Nitro crates as well

Comment: People get the idea. No reason to edit this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Rocket League wiki http://rocketleague.wikia.com/wiki/Decals:

> The Heatwave, Labyrinth, Parallax, and Slipstream decals can only be found in Champions Crate series 1, 2, and 3.
>
> The Biomass and Hexed decals can only be found in Champions Crate 4, Player's
>   Choice Crate 1 and Turbo Crate.'
>
> The 20XX and Tora decals can only be found in Turbo Crate.

These are the guaranteed crates that they will be in. The rumor you heard about getting Heatwave from CC4 is likely false. Best of luck in your crate openings if you head down that route!